# Can't close all programs and continue the upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have decided to upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 today as it is supposed to be the 1st official release date. I used the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-manager -d
```

After which I selected to continue keeping the configuration files etc. etc.

The last thing it asked was if I wanted to keep some obsolete programs at which I clicked "keep". Then told me to close all programs and continue. I used alt-tab to move to the windows I need to start closing but soon found there are no menus, and I can't use alt-tab to get back to the upgrade window, there is no unity ribbon so I guess I have no way of interacting with the PC thus al I can do is reboot and have a most likely corrupted computer.

Comment: Sorry to say but why am I voted down for a useful contribution? There may be others who have a similar experience who may find help in the question? Only trying to help... If I did not know how to use xkill I would have had no choice but to interrupt the upgrade with dire consequences. There is definitely a bug in the upgrade process which caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could start a terminal using crtl-alt-t though and used

```
xkill
```

to close the windows until I could see the update window again. I could thus continue with the upgrade. It restarted correctly and appart from a slight compiz crash it seems like it turned out well in the end.